# Lua if/elseif leading to different scenes is not working

Tags: if-statement, lua, coronasdk

This code is designed to swap from scene to scene on a timer between scene1 and scene2. When the currentBar variable counter reaches 4 it should then go to scene3 but doesn't. This example starts with scene2.

```
local composer = require ( "composer")
local scene = composer.newScene()

    local function showScene2()
        local options = {
            effect = "slideLeft",
            time = 30,
        }
    composer.gotoScene( "scene2", options)

    end

-- create scene

function scene:createScene ( event )
local sceneGroup = self.view

end 

function scene:show( event )
local sceneGroup = self.view
local phase = event.phase
    if ( phase == "will") then
        local background = display.newImage( "images/staveBlankgrey2.png", 240, 160)
        note1 =  display.newImage( "images/crDown.png", 130, 171)
        note2 =  display.newImage( "images/crUp.png", 320, 144)

        sceneGroup:insert( background )
        sceneGroup:insert( note1 )
        sceneGroup:insert( note2 )

    elseif ( phase == "did") then
        currentBar = currentBar + 1
```

This section works fine:

```
            if currentBar < 4 then 
                local function showScene2()
                    local options = {
                        effect = "slideLeft",
                        time = 30,
                    }
                composer.gotoScene( "evenBars", options)
            end
                timer.performWithDelay(tempo, showEvenBars)
```

This section doesn't work:

```
            elseif currentBar == 4 then     
                local function showEndBar()
                    local options = {
                        effect = "slideLeft",
                        time = 30,
                    }
                composer.gotoScene( "endBar", options)
            end
                timer.performWithDelay(tempo, showEndBar)

            end
    end
end

function scene:hide( event )
    local sceneGroup = self.view
    local phase = event.phase
end

function scene:destroy( event )
    local sceneGroup = self.view
end

scene:addEventListener( "create", scene)
scene:addEventListener( "show", scene)
scene:addEventListener( "hide", scene)
scene:addEventListener( "destroy", scene)

return scene
```

What am I missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see where `tempo` or `currentBar` is created so I will *assume* that they are global variables.

Regarding your problem I would probably rewrite it a little bit and create a new file (because both scene1 and scene2 will be calling this function and maybe more scenes in the future so it's better to have it in a seperate file).

And then in the scene I would add an enterFrame event listener.

Some code:

scene_swapper.lua

```
local M = {}

function M.returnSceneName( val)
    if val == nil then return nil
    elseif val == 4 then return "scene1"
    elseif val < 4 then return "scene2"
    end
end

return M
```

Event listener in my scenes:

```
local sw = require("scene_swapper")
Runtime:addEventListener( "enterFrame", 
    function()
        local swap_to_scene = sw.returnSceneName( currentBar )
        if swap_to_scene ~= nil and swap_to_scene ~= composer.getSceneName( "current" ) then 
            composer.gotoScene( swap_to_scene ) 
        end
    end 
)
```

The enterFrame listener will be checked once every frame (30 or 60 times per second) so when you update the `currentBar` value it will actually take appropriate actions.

Also don't forget to remove the enterFrame listener if you change scene.